# Animation CSSTransition React

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

Using CSSTransition component and React I want to apply a Fade In animation

here you can find a small example what I want to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/j75712qjvy

On first load time text is faded in but never again when some of the buttons below are clicked.

Each time I click in one button, state is updated and component re-rendered.
So my expectation is the fadeIn animation should restart.

What I overlook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the CssTransition to achieve this effect. It can be done with just CSS and the use of the `key` property on the element.

[See this working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zr7nnjnz4)

The key pieces of code are your element:

```
<h2 className="fadeIn" key={this.state.value}>
  {this.state.value}
</h2>
```

which I added the `key` and `className` props to. This tells react to replace it when the key changes.

Next is the associated CSS:

```
.fadeIn {
  animation: 1s fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

This applies a fading in animation every time the element is re-rendered.

**Note:** The `react-transition-group` is only needed to achieve an exit transition effect. Entry transition effects can easily be handled without it.

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been trying to get this to work with CSSTransition. Thank you!